# Changing Euclidean distance to Manhanttan

Tags: r, rweka

My Code:

```
wine_Manhanttan <- SimpleKMeans(wine, Weka_control(N=3, V=T, A = "weka.core.ManhanttanDistance"))
```

Return:

> Error in .jcall(clusterer, "V", "buildClusterer", instances) : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Trying change SimpleKMeans default Euclidean distance to Manhanttan Distance.

Comment: Class that you specified cannot be found. Check your code

Comment: possible typo: `ManhattanDistance`, not `Manha`**n**`ttanDistance`